# How to force tomcat to search a different jar?

Tags: java, tomcat

I have 2 jars in my windows tomcat lib folder.  jasperreports-3.0.0.jar and jasperreports-5.6.0.jar that have duplicate classes.   I need the 3.0.0 jar for some projects so it can't be removed.  I now have a project that needs to access a class method in the 5.6.0 jar, but it finds and tries to use the 3.0.0 class instead.

How do I force this project to use the newer jar?  In the Eclipse build path, "order and export" tab I tried moving Web App App libraries above Apache Tomcat 7, but I may not be doing something right since it's not working.

Comment: why cant the 5.6.0 jar be used inlieu of the 3.0.0? Did something fundamentally change between 5.6.0 and 3.0.0 that breaks functionality and if so can't your code be refactored to work with the new implementation?

Comment: @locus2k  It was shown that other projects break when 3.0.0 is replaced by 5.6.0.  I don't own the projects and it's not my job to fix other people's legacy code

Comment: @locus2k  I understand I can't pull in the correct class via configuration so I've modified my code to load the correct jar via urlClassLoader, but that isn't working either.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63253740/how-to-find-load-jar-in-tomcat-with-classloaderurl